# Push local git repository to a user's remote git repository using PyGithub and Python

Tags: python, git, pygithub

Task is to

1. Clone a public repository and store it locally
2. Initialize a user's new repository(target) with the repository content that you downloaded locally.

The CLI commands work perfectly but **I need to do it using python**, and when I run this code, a github login dialogue box opens and I enter the credentials and then the push works but nothing is seen on the remote repository, can we push nothing?

I have tried using subprocess module too, it does not work. I have checked every other stackoverflow solution and did not find a working solution.I need a new solution or a correction to this asap. Thanks.

```
import git

git.Repo.clone_from('https://github.com/kristej/Uniform-Database-Management.git','Uniforms')

repo = git.Repo('Uniforms')
target_repo = "https://github.com/kristej/Jojorabit.git"

# List remotes
# Reference a remote by its name as part of the object
print(f'Remote name: {repo.remotes.origin.name}')
print(f'Remote URL: {repo.remotes.origin.url}')

# Delete a default remote if already present
if repo.remotes.origin.url != target_repo:
    repo.delete_remote(repo.remotes.origin.name)

# Create a new remote
try:
    remote = repo.create_remote('origin', url=target_repo)
except git.exc.GitCommandError as error:
    print(f'Error creating remote: {error}')
    
# Reference a remote by its name as part of the object
print(f'Remote name: {repo.remotes.origin.name}')
print(f'Remote URL: {repo.remotes.origin.url}')

#Push changes
print(repo.git.push("origin", "HEAD:refs/for/master"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we push nothing?

Yes. If there's nothing to push, the push will succeed.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

---

But you're pushing to an odd location. `HEAD:refs/for/master` says to push `HEAD` to `refs/for/master`. `refs/for/master` is not a thing. I think you mean `refs/heads/master`.

But you shouldn't specify the destination unless you really need to, what `HEAD` is not `master`? Let Git figure out the source (the currently checked out branch) and its destination (the upstream of the current branch, or its best guess based on [`push.default`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)).

You just went through a bunch of work to change `origin`, you don't need to specify it again. Again, its safer to let push figure out where to push to based on the local branch configuration.

```
print(repo.git.push())
```

You also don't need to change `origin` just for one push. You can instead add a new remote and push to that.

```
repo.create_remote('other_remote', url=target_repo)
repo.git.push("other_remote")
```

Comment: Ohh! I understood it and it worked like a charm. I just started with git and tried this out. Thanks for your answer, I will read more about git.